# Laravel 8: How to store image to DB (with correct file path) and display it to the view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I am struggling with storing the image in the database, storing the filename (original name or path?) of the image to the database, storing the image with its original name in the public storage folder and displaying the image afterwards? Right now I am getting this error with the code below: Call to a member function move() on null.

create_books_table Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('author');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('book_image');
            $table->string('amazon');
            $table->string('goodreads');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\BookController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Auth::routes();

/*--------------- Website Views ---------------*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('pages.about');
});

Route::get('/books', function () {
    return view('pages.books');
});


/*--------------- Admin Views ---------------*/
/*--- Home Controller ---*/
Route::get('/home', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.home');
Route::get('/home/create', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'create'])->name('admin.create');
Route::post('/home', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'store'])->name('home.store');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Book;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $books = Book::all();
        return view('admin.home', compact('books'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.create');
    }

    
    public function store(Request $request,)
    {
    // Validate User Input
    $inputs = request()->validate([
        'author' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'book_image' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'],
        'amazon' => ['required', 'string', 'max:4068'],
        'goodreads' => ['required', 'string', 'max:4068']
    ]);

    // Change book_image name to original name and store in public storage folder.
    if ($request->hasFile('book_image')) {
        $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->book_image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('book-images'), $imageName);
    }

    // Create Book Object
    $book = new Book([
        "author" => $request->get('author'),
        "title" => $request->get('title'),
        "book_image" => $request->file($imageName),
        "amazon" => $request->get('amazon'),
        "goodreads" => $request->get('goodreads')
    ]);

        // Save the Record to DB
        $book->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.home');
    }
}
```

home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    {{-- If Authorized: Show This Page --}}
    @if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
    @endif

    <div>
        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 1rem; text-align:center">Kara's Home Page</h2>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.create') }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem">Create
            Book</a>
    </div>

    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h2 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-secondary">Edited Books</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Amazon Url</th>
                            <th>Goodreads Url</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Amazon Url</th>
                            <th>Goodreads Url</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>

                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($books as $book)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $book->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $book->author }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $book->title }}</td>
                            <td><img src="{{ $book->book_image }}" alt="Book Image" height="40px"></td>
                            <td>{{ $book->amazon }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $book->goodreads }}</td>

                            {{-- Form Buttons Are More Secure --}}
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ route('admin.edit', $book->id) }}"
                                    class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post" action="{{ route('home.destroy', $book->id) }}"
                                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('DELETE')
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination justify-content-center">
        {{-- {{ $posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }} --}}
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Information

I have tried a million different ways to change the file path name. I just want the correct way to do this, so the image will display.

Comment: What's your specific question about this code? Do you struggle with storing the image in the database, storing the filename of the image to the database and the file itself to a storage, or with displaying the image afterwards?

Comment: All of the above.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain more details about this, especially about the approaches to resolve the problem

Comment: I just did, maybe you can look at it. Again, I also changed the code to reflect what I think the other persons solution might be, but I am still lost.

Answer (score 1):

update

```
    $request->book_image->getRealPath()->store('book', 'public');
```

add this

```
 getRealPath()
```

and lock this

```
$name = $request->book_image->getClientOriginalName()
$filename = $request->book_image->getRealPath() 
$extension = $request->book_image->extension()
```

or

```
$name = $request->book_image->getClientOriginalName() ;
$filename = pathinfo($request->book_image, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($request->book_image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: So I add the two statements to my if statement correct: $request->book_image->getRealPath()->store('book', 'public');  && $request->book_image->getClientOriginalName();

Comment: I got an Error: Call to a member function store() on string

Comment: try 
this
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->book_image->extension();  
     
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer seems cryptic to me. I am not sure what variable the path or the original name of the image is stored under and how to add that variable to my book object. I can see how some of this might work, but not the full picture. I have revised the code above, maybe you can look at how I am trying to implement your solution. Thank you.